# Where are "Auto backup" photos stored?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a S4 (4.3, verizon) and want to download the photos I have in "Auto backup" in my gallery. It has a picassa web albums logo ([this](http://media.motoricerca.net/upload/picasa-logo.png) thing) on it, but I can't find it on:

- My phone, when connected via MTP (I tried searching for a specific image as well)
- Google+ images
- Picasa web albums

I want to *somehow* download it, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Auto Backup access there are several options open to you.

1. Phone: Select the **Gallery** app which should bring up a listing of your **Albums**. One of your albums will be titled **Auto Backup** (assuming you have photos/videos in the album - otherwise the album will not appear).
2. Website: [Google+ Auto Backup](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/search/%23AutoBackup)
3. Website: [Picasa Web](https://picasaweb.google.com/home?alabel=instant_upload)

Comment: There are 1000+ images on my phone in auto backup but only a few hundred on those links. Also I'm trying to export them, what do I do for #1?

Comment: You can go to the Google+ app > settings > Auto Backup > Backup all. The photos should then appear on both websites. If they are only on your phone, then plug your phone into a computer and open up windows explorer Computer > [name of device] > Internal storage > DCIM > Camera.

Comment: Auto Backup photos on your phone and websites should be identical. There is no reason for them not to be. Perhaps there is an album with a similar name? In Picasa sometimes this album is named "instant upload"

Answer (score 0):

You can access them from the Google+ website.  There is an auto backup album under photos.